# Change format of existing date

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to format a date to look like this `2011-09-19`

If I do the following :

```
leaveDate = "09/19/11"
FormatTime, fileDate, leaveDate, yyyy-MM-dd
MsgBox, %fileDate%
```

It will just pick up the current date and time because my input date format is invalid. How can I take this `09/19/11` and turn it into this `2011-09-19`?

I have read the [docs](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FormatTime.htm), and I can't find a function to do this. Am I just overlooking it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date needs to be supplied in [YYYYMMDDHH24MISS](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileSetTime.htm#YYYYMMDD) format. If your date format is consistent and all years are after 2000 then the following code using [SubStr()](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Functions.htm#SubStr) to split up the date should work:

```
leaveDate := "09/19/11"

year := "20" . SubStr(leaveDate, 8, 2)
month := SubStr(leaveDate, 2, 2)
date := SubStr(leaveDate, 5, 2)
formattedTime := year . month . date

FormatTime, fileDate, %formattedTime%, yyyy-MM-dd
MsgBox, %fileDate%
```

At the bottom of the documentation page for FormatTime [a link is given to a forum topic](http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic20405.html) giving the code for a function titled DateParse. This function will take a date in pretty much any format and return a YYYYMMDDHH24MISS formatted string that can be used instead of SubStr() generated string.

The example given is:

```
DateParse("2:35 PM, 27 November 2007")
```